# Can I safely use the non-generic DbContextOptions in ASP.NET Core and EF Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core

In ASP.NET Core, an EF Core context is created by the builtin DI container. In the [official documentation](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro#create-the-database-context), a context is created with a generic `DbContextOptions<TContext>`:

```
public class MyContext : IdentityDbContext<User> {
  public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options, ILogger<MyContext) logger) : base(options) { }
}
```

However, there are examples of the non-generic as well:

```
public class MyContext : IdentityDbContext<User> {
  public MyContext(DbContextOptions options, ILogger<MyContext) logger) : base(options) { }
}
```

The difference between them according to the source code is:

> Type parameters: TContext: The type of the context these options apply to.

I'd like to use the non-generic type, because in my design I have an abstract context, and that doesn't play well with the DI container.

*So, if I use the non-generic type, what does that really mean? That my context won't be properly configured?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'd like to use the non-generic type, because in my design I have an abstract context, and that doesn't play well with the DI container.

That plays just fine with the DI container. It only looks at the most-derived type, the type it's trying to instantiate. The fact that there's a base class somewhere in between is not relevant.

Note that while you cannot use `DbContextOptions<AbstractDbContext>`, you do not need to. You can either make the base class take `DbContextOptions`, or make the base class generic and take `DbContextOptions<ConcreteDbContext>`:

```
abstract class AbstractDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected AbstractDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}

class ConcreteDbContext : AbstractDbContext
{
    public ConcreteDbContext(DbContextOptions<ConcreteDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

or

```
abstract class AbstractDbContext<TContext> : DbContext
    where TContext : AbstractDbContext<TContext>
{
    protected AbstractDbContext(DbContextOptions<TContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}

class ConcreteDbContext : AbstractDbContext<ConcreteDbContext>
{
    public ConcreteDbContext(DbContextOptions<ConcreteDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

---

> So, if I use the non-generic type, what does that really mean? That my context won't be properly configured?

A constructor taking a non-generic `DbContextOptions` usually works as well. Normally, you'd be right, the service provider wouldn't be able to figure this out. However, EF Core specifically informs the service container, when you call `serviceCollection.AddDbContext<ConcreteDbContext>(...)`, that when a `DbContextOptions` instance is requested, a `DbContextOptions<ConcreteDbContext>` instance should be provided.

Note that this only works if you have a single context type. If you have multiple, the service provider doesn't have enough information to figure out which one you need.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the signature of the base `IdentityDbContext` class (generic and non generic) [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore.identitydbcontext-8#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Identity_EntityFrameworkCore_IdentityDbContext_8__ctor_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbContextOptions_):

```
public IdentityDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
```

Which to me means it can work with non generic `DbContextOptions` without a problem.

In fact the only difference between the [generic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptions-1) and [non generic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptions#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbContextOptions) versions of the `DbContextOptions` class is that the generic version implements the `abstract` non generic version.

Still, passing `DbContextOptions<YourDbContext>` to `YourDbContext` constructor is safer because it ensures the caller will pass the correct implementation of the abstract class (basically the [`ContextType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptions-1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbContextOptions_1_ContextType) property).

Comment: I think that maybe it is safe to use non-generic, UNLESS, you have two different contexts in your project. Then you need to use generic options class, to ensure each context is configured correctly.